# Java app (Chat server + client) deployment via chef?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, chef-infra

I have created simple Java ChatServer and ChatClient. The ChatServer is a stand-alone program (JVM). ChatClient has the GUI for messaging, connects to ChatServer and so on. These two works find on my workstation. I open ChatServer for connection first, then ChatClient works.

Now, I was told to use Chef to deploy this Java app. I have read tutorials on Chef. I have went through the installation of Chef Development Kit and done some examples. It seems like there are a lot more to it..

What are some suggested ways to deploy Java app via Chef? I think I will need to make it a .war file.. and probably use Tomcat?  If this is to be deployed via Chef, do I still need ChatServer that uses JVM? Can anyone provide some guidance on the basic steps I need to take in order for me to accomplish this?

I will add any code if necessary.. 
I am a beginner and really confused here.. any advice would be helpful!

Comment: Off-toppic for stackoverflow, your application server and client seem to work fine, which means you have no problem with the coding part. You don't seem to have a web application until you mention `.war` and `tomcat`? Do you know what those are?

Comment: I want to know the possible ways of doing this so I can study the necessary tools. I only know coding part, pretty basic stuff.

Comment: I was thinking of transforming my ChatServer into a war application and drop it in Tomcat to start it.. then I am lost

Answer (score 0):

When starting out with Chef the best way is generally to do the setup by hand, note down what commands you wrote, and then build a recipe out of those. `apt-get install` or `yum install` become package resources, `mkdir` becomes directory, any files you edit become template resources, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Installing applications and more importantly installing an application's dependencies is tough and you need to decide where that effort is best spent.

You can choose to automate what I call a "manual" install. Copy each file onto the target machine and setup the service to run the chat server. Or you can spend time creating either an RPM, Debian or MSI package (depends on your target platform) to do perform all the necessary actions to install your app.

Personally I dislike complex application deploy logic. My preference is to use chef to capture my host dependencies and ideally have an application install that is as simple as possible "yum install myapp" or "apt-get install myapp". The extra effort spent learning how to integrate your application into its target OS generally always pays off in the long run. Simpler to install and later simpler to upgrade.

Finally I recommend the [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) tool. Hopefully you'll find it useful.

### Chef doing a "manual" install

```
include_recipe "java"

remote_file "/opt/myapp/chatserver.jar" do
  source "http://mydistibserver/chatserver.jar"
  checksum "XXXXXX.."
end

remote_file "/opt/myapp/chatclient.jar" do
  source "http://mydistibserver/chatclient.jar"
  checksum "YYYY.."
end

remote_file "/opt/myapp/myapp" do
  source "http://mydistibserver/myapp"
  checksum "ZZZZ.."
end

..
..

service "myapp_service" do
  supports :status => true, :restart => true
  start_command "/opt/myapp/myapp start"
  restart_command "/opt/myapp/myapp restart"
  status_command "/opt/myapp/myapp status"
  action [ :enable, :start ]
end
```

Note:

- This is not the best way to setup and run a background service. It'll work but your better off running a proper process manager lik supervisord or runit.

### Chef doing a "package" install

```
package "myapp"
```

Note:

- This chef recipe would be cross platform, would install an RPM or Debian package depending on the platform being run on.
- All dependencies are expressed in the package metadata and installed automating by the package manager, not by chef.